# Delete char at position in string

Tags: java, string

Currently, I am working on a project that requires to delete a char at a set position in a string.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [`String#charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

Answer (score 18):

Use a StringBuilder, which has the method `deleteCharAt()`.  Then, you can just use `stringBuilder.toString()` to get your string.

EDIT, here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "bla*h";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);
    sb.deleteCharAt(3);
    // Prints out "blah"
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Strings are **immutable** ! But to accomplish your task, you can

1. Copy the substring from the start of the string to the character that has to be deleted
2. Copy the substring from the character that has to be deleted to the end of the String.
3. Append the second String to the first one.

For example, let's say you have to remove the third character:

```
String input = "Hello, World";
String first = input.substring(0, 3);
String second = input.substring(4);
String result = first + second;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your string to `StringBuilder`, which have convinient `deletaCharAt` method.

```
String strWithoutChar = new StringBuilder(yourString).deleteCharAt(yourIndex).toString();
```

But keep in mind, this gives to you ability to remove some boilerplate code, but it takes more memory in compassion to using `String#substring` method.

Comment: People are more likely to vote up your answers if you include a description of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The way you would do this is by copying the oldstring into a newstring, being careful to remove the one character, like so:

```
String newString = oldString.substring(0, index) + oldString.substring(index+1);
```

Keep in mind that if you are doing this several times, constantly making new strings is rather inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is being said here by fellow scholars, I agree to them that it gives the correct answer. But if you are dealing with a production level program where every loophole gets magnified, I would suggest you to not use "Substring" method of string because:

(1). substring method actually leaves the parent string unflagged for garbage collector. Due to this garbage collector cannot clean it up in its process, the heap space gets occupied and unused parent strings still remains to exist in the heap space even when it is\ not in use.

(2). If you deal with a number of string manipulations such as these, it may eventually result in 'Out of Heap Memory' exception which is not desirable at any point in time in the program.

Use char array and its manipulations to achieve what you want :

```
public static void fn1()
{
 String a = "Stack Overflow";
 char[] b = a.toCharArray();
 j // index position of the character that you want to delete
 for(int i=j;i<b.length-1;i++)
 {
     b[i]=b[i+1];
 }
 b[b.length-1]='\000'; // '\000' is the null character

 System.out.println(new String(b));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the substring method but using concat instead of +

```
String removeCharAt(String s, int index) {
    return s.substring(0, index).concat(s.substring(index + 1));
}
```